# How to access JDBC calls in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I m developing a plugin in Eclipse using Java , as plugin requirement I need to retrieve database table values in to my java class(Presently I m using SQL Server2008 database). I also added the *jtds1.2.5.jar*  in libraries , still I m not able to get the results

can any one help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to [turn JDBC debugging up](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in's classpath **must** be specified using the MANIFEST.MF file, whether that means a .jar file you're including in the plug-in or other plug-ins you depend upon.  If NoClassDefFoundErrors are not why you can't get your JDBC results, it would help to give more information on the errors you're encountering.

Comment: I m not getting any errors just I m not able to view the results of the database , I m confusing here